# WSL-2 DNS is not working with VPN connection on Win 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, vpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have WSL Version 2 running on my Windows 10 Laptop. I'm using the WSL distribution Ubuntu-20.04.
When I connect to a VPN network domain name resolution doesn't work so I can't access the Internet.

VPN Client in use is "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client"

I tried the following steps to resolve this problem.

1. Opening the Windows command prompt in admin mode
2. Execute following commands

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset all
netsh winhttp reset proxy
ipconfig /flushdns
reboot
```

That worked once, I had access to the internet.
But as soon as I disconnected the VPN connection and connected again, I had the same problem all over again. I tried to just execute the commands again and rebooted, but now thats not working anymore.

What is a permanent fix for this problem?

Comment: I'd recommend moving this over to [Super User](https://superuser.com) since it isn't directly programming related, and thus off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PulseSecure VPN prevents WSL2 internet connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63972437/pulsesecure-vpn-prevents-wsl2-internet-connectivity)

Comment: @piouson: the mention question not available, can you open this question or share another similar question please? I have exactly same issue.

Comment: @Amir I fixed my issue with [wsl-vpnfix](https://github.com/sakai135/wsl-vpnkit)

Comment: This answer here -> https://superuser.com/a/1718953/953434 works for sure irrespective of your distribution. Ubuntu or Debian or any other

Comment: Just reinstall AnyConnect: https://superuser.com/a/1723900/868946

Answer (score 54):

There is an issue with DNS Forwarding in WSL2 when using VPN ([see github Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1350)). Plus there is a issue with the *Cisco AnyConnect*. So here is a workaround for these problems. Should work for Ubuntu and Debian.

### Workaround (new - automatic)

This solution is automatic and was created by **EdwardCooke** (see https://www.frakkingsweet.com/automatic-dns-configuration-with-wsl-and-anyconnect-client/). This is just the first part of his solution **updating resolv.conf when starting WSL.**

1. **Re-enable auto generation of resolv.conf** (if disabled)

   by commented the disable with `#`

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf
   ```

   ```bash
   #[network]
   #generateResolvConf = false
   ```
2. **Create the script**

   ```bash
   sudo nano /bin/vpn-dns.sh
   ```

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash

   echo "Getting current DNS servers, this takes a couple of seconds"

   /mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -Command '
   $ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
   Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription "Cisco AnyConnect*" | Get-DnsClientServerAddress | Select -ExpandProperty ServerAddresses
   Get-NetAdapter | ?{-not ($_.InterfaceDescription -like "Cisco AnyConnect*") } | Get-DnsClientServerAddress | Select -ExpandProperty ServerAddresses
   ' | \
           awk 'BEGIN { print "# Generated by vpn fix func on", strftime("%c"); print } { print "nameserver", $1 }' | \
           tr -d '\r' > /etc/resolv.conf
   clear
   ```
3. **Make it executable/run as sudo**

   ```bash
   sudo chmod +x /bin/vpn-dns.sh
   echo "$(whoami) ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/vpn-dns.sh" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/010-$(whoami)-vpn-dns
   ```
4. Make it **run** on **wsl startup**

   ```bash
   echo "/bin/vpn-dns.sh" | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/vpn-dns.sh
   ```

You can also run it manually:
`sudo /bin/vpn-dns.sh`

### Workaround (old manual)

1. Find out nameserver with **windows powershell** (during VPN Session)

   ```
   nslookup
   ```

   You'll get the IPv4 adress of your corporate nameserver
   Copy this address.
2. Disable *resolv.conf* generation **in wsl:**

   ```bash
   sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf
   ```

   copy this text to the file (to disable resolve.conf generation, when wsl starts up)

   ```bash
   [network]                                                                        
   generateResolvConf = false
   ```
3. **In wsl** Add your corporate nameserver to `resolv.conf`

   ```bash
   sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
   ```

   Remove other entries and add your corporate nameserver IP (if you have a secondary nameserver, add it in a separate line)

   - `nameserver X.X.X.X` (where X.X.X.X is your address obtained in step 1)
4. Set your VPN adapter (if you have *Cisco AnyConnect*) **open a admin powershell**

   - Find out your VPN adapter name: `Get-NetIPInterface` (in my case: `"Cisco AnyConnect"`)
   - Set adapter metric (Replace -Match with your name), **in my case I have to run this after ever reboot or VPN reconnect**:

   ```
   Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 6000
   ```

   ([What is interface metric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/automatic-metric-for-ipv4-routes): Used to determine route, windows use interface with lowest metric)
5. Restart wsl **in powershell**: `wsl.exe --shutdown`
6. Test it **in wsl** run: `wget google.com` - if this command works, you are done.

In my case I get DNS issues when try to connect to internal stuff via browser (on Windows 10, f.e.: intranet), caused by the high metric value set in step 4 (basically kind of disabling VPN Route). So here is the workaround for the workaround:

1. Check your default metric (of VPNs Interface) **in powershell** (replace -Match with your interface name)

```
Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Get-NetIPInterface
```

2. When running into problems on Windows 10 restore this default value with **admin powershell** (replace value at the end with your default value):

```
Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 1
```

Comment: `wget : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
At line:1 char:1
+ wget google.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand`

Comment: It seems like you‘re running whet in powershell, you should try that in the wsl instance not on windows

Comment: My personal [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71162377/17840900) (1/2 based on yours)

Comment: I was having a lot of trouble with this issue... and with AlmaLinux and Sophos Connect as VPN. Your solution worked for me! At least part of it... just steps 1-3 and restarting WSL did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: When I run `Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object  -FilterScript {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"}| Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric`, I get the error
`Set-NetIPInterface : No matching MSFT_NetIPInterface objects found by CIM query for instances of the ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetIPInterface class on
the  CIM server: SELECT * FROM MSFT_NetIPInterface  WHERE ((InterfaceIndex = 19)) AND ((InterfaceAlias LIKE 'Ethernet 2')). Verify query parameters
and retry.`

Comment: @Phalgun you can run `Get-NetAdapter -Name *` to find out the name of the corresponding vpn network adapter

Comment: Getting permission denied on startup. Not working.

Comment: The updated fix does not work. Please include the process to undo the changes so it doesn't appear at every startup.

Comment: it helps only before you restart openvpn connection

Comment: and also I found it fixes dns only inside wsl, outside windows dns still broken... /me thinking to return back to linux desktop, it is really flustrate

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me.

> How Anyconnect v4.9 breaks it: It adds a route for wsl2 with a low
> metric 2, lower than 5256, which causes vpn becomes the chosen route,
> and of course that will never work. As seen below. c:> route.exe print
> Note: “172.17.228.192 255.255.255.240” is the wsl2 destination subnet.
> 172.17.228.192 255.255.255.240 On-link 172.17.228.193 5256
> 172.17.228.192 255.255.255.240 10.255.0.1 10.255.0.71 2 This problem is solved when I change the vpn route metric to 5500, higher than
> 5256, by doing so: Control Panel – network – click the vpn – property
> – IPv4 – property, advanced – automatic metric: uncheck it and type in
> 5500.

source: https://riowingwp.wordpress.com/2020/12/13/anyconnect-bug/

Comment: TLDR; `Control Panel -> Network adapters -> VPN adapter properties -> IPv4 -> Advanced -> Interface metric 5500`

Comment: While this does fix the issue, the value gets reset every time you disconnect and reconnect to the VPN. How to set permanently?

Answer (score 4):

There is an issue with VPN integration in WSL running on my Windows 10. You need to redirect WSL to VPN, please follow these steps:

STEP-1: Obtain DNS address from Windows Power Shell

```
>nslookup
Servidor predeterminado:  yyyy.com
Address:  x.x.x.x
```

or

```
>ipconfig /all
```

STEP-2 Open Ubuntu-20.04 Version 2 WSL and  open /etc/resolv.conf

STEP-3 Modify /etc/resolv.conf . Add the VPN Address in the first position(I deleted the others directions but it is not necessary), save the file, and try to access again. My file looks like:

```
nameserver X.X.X.X
```

Comment: I must add the VPN IP assigned my PC or the VPN GW?

Comment: Thank you @Poropb, this solved the problem for me. Just moved in /etc/resolv.conf the VPN IP at the top of the others.
BTW in my case at the top was my local router IP - 192.168.0.1.

Comment: The IP address was already at first position, still not working.

Answer (score 1):

All that i needed from @kraego answer is

```
Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Get-NetIPInterface
```

I couldn't ping 8.8.8.8, but with the metric change it started to work.

```
Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match 'Cisco AnyConnect'} | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 6000
```

And added it in a window task

[Event trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiWmj.png)

Action start Powershell.exe. Parameters: -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match 'Cisco AnyConnect'} | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 6000"

But always i need to start wsl before connect VPN

Comment: Your quote doesn't even include the metric change that helped you

Comment: You are rigth, edited