# Issue Connecting to SQL Server Using PyODBC on WSL2 - VPN (AnyConnect) Required - Windows 11

Tags: sql-server, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pyodbc, vpn

```
conn=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                'Server=servername, 1433;'
                'Database=database;'  
                'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

This is the sql connection I have. This code **works as expected on Windows 11**. But when running on WSL2 on the same PC it gives error message

```
('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Connecting to the database requires VPN connection using AnyConnect. I followed instructions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66444822/wsl-2-dns-is-not-working-with-vpn-connection-on-win-10) to update the resolv.conf file. But the problem still persists. I'm not sure if there is still something wrong with VPN or it's something else.

Very much appreciated the help!

Comment: `Trusted_Connection=yes` implies authentication using the running process's Active Directory/Kerberos authentication token. So is your WSL2 container domain joined to the same  Active Directory/Kerberos domain as the target SQL Server? If not you'll need to use SQL Logon authentication with a username and password (`UID` and `PWD`).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thank you for the comment. I tried UID and PWD, but it doesn't work. I think it's because of SSO. I assume my WSL is not joined to the Active Directory/Kerberos domain because I've never done anything to set it up. I tried to google how to join them but wasn't able to find anything helpful. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks.